# AB testing - statistical significance of non-binomial metrics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I got the following test results:

```
+---------+-------+-------------+-------+
| Variant | Size  | Conversions | Sales |
+---------+-------+-------------+-------+
| A       | 20472 |         394 | $6542 |
| B       | 20304 |         380 | $8812 |
+---------+-------+-------------+-------+
```

It's easy to check (e.g. using [this calculator](http://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/chi-squared.html)) that difference in **conversions** is statistically insignificant.

But how do I check the significance for **sales**?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you think of any potentially relevant formulas?

Comment: I used the formulas listed here: https://splitmetrics.com/blog/mobile-a-b-testing-statistical-significance/. They work well for conversions, but they do not suit sales or sales-per-user types of metrics.

Comment: @VadimTikanov, hi do you have any thoughts now?